# Entity Framework Azure SaveChanges - datetime, incorrect by one hour

Tags: sql, entity-framework, azure, entity-framework-6

I'm using EF6.  I get a record, then I update it.  One of the columns is a datetime column but it updates it incorrectly.  The sql that Entity Framework produces appears correct but when the sql is executed the hour is incorrect in the database.  It seems to update the other columns properly.

Whether the fault lies with sql, EF or Azure I'm unsure?

Here is my EF log

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Fixtures]
SET [FixtureExternalId] = NULL, [SoccerFixtureId] = @0, [HomeTeamId] = @1, [AwayTeamId] = @2, [Date] = @3, [HomeScore] = @4, [AwayScore] = @5, [FixtureStatus] = @6, [InPlayTime] = @7, [CompetitionId] = @8, [CompetitionStage] = @9 WHERE ([FixtureId] = @10)
-- @0: '338066' (Type = Int32)
-- @1: '409' (Type = Int32)
-- @2: '842' (Type = Int32)
-- @3: '23/07/2014 16:00:00' (Type = DateTime2)
-- @4: '3' (Type = Int32)
-- @5: '0' (Type = Int32)
-- @6: '3' (Type = Int32)
-- @7: '89'' (Type = String, Size = -1)
-- @8: '15' (Type = Int32)
-- @9: '0' (Type = Int32)
-- @10: '12467' (Type = Int32)
-- Executing at 23/07/2014 18:31:37 +01:00

-- Completed in 34 ms with result: 1
```

As you can see of the update statement says 15:00 but after this sql has been executed and I do a sql select of the record I get
2014-07-23 **15:00:00.000**

Why is the time one hour out?

Thanks

Comment: All azure products are UTC by default.  I'd imagine that because you're not passing in a timezone, one is being provided for you.

Comment: Hi, do you know how I specify the timezone?

Comment: The app is running in Azure and so is the database, why the difference?

Comment: "I do a sql select of the record I get 2014-07-23 15:00:00.000" >>> What tool have you done your SELECT with?

Answer (score 2):

It is true SQL Azure databases use UTC timezone (see [this post](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/greg_low/archive/2013/01/20/windows-azure-sql-database-getdate-sysdatetime-sysutcdatetime-and-rounding.aspx)). You can verify it by running `SELECT GETDATE()`, which will return UTC date and time.

It also seems your application uses UTC **+1** timezone (based on your EF log: "Executing at 23/07/2014 18:31:37 **+01:00**").

However, as long as you are using `System.DateTime` in your code and `DATETIME` / `DATETIME2` in your database, the above assertions are irrelevant. In fact:

- SQL `DATETIME` / `DATETIME2` do not store timezone information. So, by design, both are timezone agnostic. No timezone offset on the database server itself is applied, according to [this comment](http://blog.dezfowler.com/2010/07/utc-gotchas-in-net-and-sql-server.html?showComment=1288086299470#c893131032757334348).
- EF6 is also timezone agnostic. After browsing the source code, I found EF6 ignores the `Kind` property of `System.DateTime` values, and never calls `ToLocalTime`, `ToUniversalTime`, nor any other timezone offsetting method. The log formatter is also reliable, as it is a simple call to `object.ToString`.

Now back to your questions:

> Whether the fault lies with sql, EF or Azure I'm unsure? Why is the
>   time one hour out?

The most likely answer is that the fault relies neither with SQL, EF nor Azure.
Here are a few other possibilities:

- The value was updated again before observation
- If observing the value using a SQL management tool like SQL Data Tools, maybe the tool is applying some conversion at display
- A trigger applies some transformation of the [Date] column
- The observed value (2014-07-23 15:00:00.000) is the result of a call to `DateTime.ToLocalTime` or `DateTime.ToUniversalTime` methods after it was loaded from the database
- The value you observed is offsetted by some JSON or XML serialization/deserialization (see [this post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973825.aspx#datetime_topic9) > The Special Case of XML) after it was loaded from the database

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use [datetimeoffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx) in ISO 8601 format to mantain local: YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[.nnnnnnn][{+|-}hh:mm] for an offset or YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[.nnnnnnn]Z for UTC (Azure works in UTC time).

In code, you can try `DateTime.ToLocalTime` or `DateTime.ToUniversalTime`

Comment: --@3: '2014-07-2316:00:00Z' (Type = datetimeoffset) or '2014-07-2316:00:00+01:00'

Comment: I don't have access to the way Entity Framework creates the sql.  As far as I'm aware it will always be a DateTime2 datatype